# Executing VSTS Performance test via Command Prompt

Tags: performance, visualstudio

I am executing VSTS Performance test (that is .webtest file) using the command prompt, test runs successfully when I specify the name of the result file explicitly. But when I don't specify that and I want VSTS to generate the result .trx file on its own (with timestamp and machine name), then the test fails.

**Currently I am using this:**

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest.exe/TestContainer:"C:\Path\TC.webtest" /testsettings:"C:\Path2\Local.testsettings"

**and getting an error:**

> Error when trying to save result file: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\username_Mac 2016-05-26 11_18_41.trx'.

Actually I don't have permissions to write to this location `'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\'`, so I am getting this error.

Is there a way in which I can specify only the path of Result File through command prompt (where I have write permissions) and then VSTS will automatically creates the result file at that location with the naming syntax. In short I don't want to change the Result File name manually, every time test is executed via cmd, it should create a new file.

I have gone through the following links and using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2008/12/22/running-web-and-load-tests-from-the-command-line/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx#Anchor_1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155804.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The command used is

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>MSTest.exe/TestContainer:"C:\Path\TC.webtest" /testsettings:"C:\Path2\Local.testsettings"
```

This means that the current directory is

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
```

and the command being executed is

```
MSTest.exe/TestContainer:"C:\Path\TC.webtest" /testsettings:"C:\Path2\Local.testsettings"
```

In theses circumstances `mstest.exe` tries to write the results to a subdirectory of the current directory.

The solution is to set the current directory to be where you want the results, or to a parent of that directory. The following command should work:

```
cd C:\Path\
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /TestContainer:"TC.webtest" /testsettings:"C:\Path2\Local.testsettings"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) But I observed one thing that if I execute load test for 5 users via Command Prompt then Response time is much less than the same load test executed via Visual Studio. Is that a normal behavior? or I am doing something wrong?